# Stream instead of byte[] in wCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, stream

I am developing a WCF Service for Uploading a document, previously I was using `byte[]` and now the requirement has changed to use `Stream`

I am using an external WSDL file for the WCF.

I have changed the signature of my functions which used byte[] to Stream, but now when I create a Client, the Upload function asking the same input parameter as previous.

Can you please help me in this.

What wrong. I cannot change the WSDL file. My WSDL file is using `base64Binary` for byte[] and this is enough for Stream too.

Server Code:

```
public Response Upload(RequestClass req)
{

}

public RequestClass{
    HeaderClass Header;
    Stream content;
}
```

Code generated in Client:

```
public Response Upload(Header hdr, byte[] content);
```

***Updated:***

```
<xs:element name="UploadDocumentReqMsg">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UploadDocumentContent" nillable="true" type="str:Stream"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="UploadDocumentReqHdr" nillable="true" type="tns:RequestHeader"/>
```

My request in WSDL, so for both byte[] and Stream, I was using Stream.

Comment: Did you read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx ?

Comment: Ok, How do you generate the proxy client?

Comment: How does the DataContract for RequestClass looks like, and why dont you pass a new RequestClass in the client code?

Comment: when ever i create an object for Server, the upload method has two parameter even though i gave only one in server

Comment: this is because i had a constructor for RequestClass which accepts Header and Content

Comment: Hard to say why its not working for you! How do you update you proxy client? If you use the Service Reference in VS, how does the Reference.cs file look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean that you cannot change the WSDL? You need the new WSDL file (with the new signature) to generate the client properly.

When using Stream and WCF there are some limitations regarding binding, here is a link about that:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36973/Stream-Operation-in-WCF

Cheers
--Jocke